# Embedded databases for ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, rdbms, embedded-database

I need an embedded database solution that can be used from within an ASP.NET application. Unfortunately, it seems that SQL Server compact edition does not support ASP.NET and my web host does not avail me SQL Server. 
MS Access is an option. But would like to have some better open source solutions. Thank you.

Comment: As of version 4, asp.net does support sql compact

Comment: By "not avail me" do you mean that it is just not available or do you mean also that you are not allowed to install it?

Comment: No, I am not allowed to install too..

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options:

1. Sql server compact 4.0. It works with asp.net, check [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx).
2. Sqlite, it works well with asp.net, get connection from [Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) connector site.
3. Firebird. [provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/development-net-provider/), [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/EmbeddedFirebird.aspx)
4. [Db4o](http://www.db4o.com/)
5. [VistaDb](http://www.vistadb.net/)
6. MySql Embedded

I would recommend Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is very popular. There are several .NET bindings available from 3rd party vendors.

Comment: @mihsathe - I don't see why not, though I haven't tried it personally. I know that many websites do use it for a data store, although I cannot say what languages they were written in.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express Edition is an option, but it may not be appropriate for high volume sites as it has a connections limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQllite](http://andrewchaa.me.uk/2009/10/20/use-sqlite-together-wtih-asp-net-mvc/) which is a file based small scale database.  It does have limitation however.

Sql express still needs to be installed on the server so you would have to check the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind against network database model, you can try this: https://github.com/mdsoftware/mData. Lisp-like data processing language and expression compiler/execution machine are an options.